# NoSQL Document-oriented in-memory database written in Java

Tags: java, nosql, in-memory-database

The goals are:

- Open source
- Written in Java
- Available as a Jar file
- Should not need the installation or configuration of a server or a client
- Be document-oriented as MongoDB, CouchDB, etc.
- Work as in-memory database
- Available in Maven

[Hazelcast](http://hazelcast.com) works like that, but it's not document-oriented.

Do you know any NoSQL database with that description?

Comment: No, but please describe your *use cases*, so that we can find an suiting technology for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I found it. It uses Cassandra as an in-memory embedded server. The libraries are written on Java and they are available on Maven.

https://github.com/doanduyhai/Achilles/wiki/CQL-embedded-cassandra-server